# Keep getting Runtime error(SIGSEGV) on a programming website even though it works on my system

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime-error, unordered-map, greedy

I'm solving this problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/FGFS.
I'm not able to find the reason why I'm getting Runtime error(SIGSEGV). The code works on my system but I can't find where the mistake is.

At first I thought I was getting the error because I didn't take into account the edge case (N = 0) and was accessing unallocated memory through the iterators but I'm still getting runtime error ever after fixing it.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Interval
{
    int s, f;
    Interval(int _s = 0, int _f = 0)
        : s(_s), f(_f) {}
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Interval& I)
    {
        return in >> I.s >> I.f;
    }
};

class Comparator
{
public:
    bool operator() (const Interval& I1, const Interval& I2) const
    {
        return I1.f < I2.f;
    }
};

bool intersect(const Interval& I1, const Interval& I2)          // two intervals intersect if the departure time of the first is greater than the arrival time of the second (Note that they are already sorted according to Comparator())
{
    return I1.f > I2.s;
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    cin >> T;

    while (T--)
    {
        int N, K;
        cin >> N >> K;

        if (N == 0)
        {
            cout << 0 << endl;
            continue;
        }

        unordered_map<int, vector<Interval>> R;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            Interval I;
            int p;
            cin >> I >> p;

            R[p].push_back(I);
        }

        for (auto itr = R.begin(); itr != R.end(); ++itr)
            sort(itr->second.begin(), itr->second.end(), Comparator());     // sort the vector at each compartment based on the departure time of the customers

        int count = 0;
        for (auto itr = R.cbegin(); itr != R.cend(); ++itr)
        {
            const vector<Interval>& C = itr->second;

            ++count;
            size_t k = 0;
            for (size_t i = 1; i < C.size(); ++i)                           // greedy algorithm to count the size of the maximal set of non-conflicting intervals at that respective compartment
                if (!intersect(C[k], C[i]))
                {
                    ++count;
                    k = i;
                }
        }

        cout << count << endl;
    }
}
```

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 30
0 ≤ N ≤ 105
1 ≤ K ≤ 109
0 ≤ si < fi ≤ 109
1 ≤ pi ≤ K
```

Example input and output:

Input:

```
2
3 3
1 3 1
4 6 2
7 10 3
4 2
10 100 1
100 200 2
150 500 2
200 300 2
```

Output:

```
3
3
```

Getting Runtime error(SIGSEGV) on the website but works fine on my system.

Comment: Try running it under valgrind ?

Comment: One of the bad things about such sites is that they don't publish their data-sets, which makes it very hard to properly debug your applications.

Comment: And the only questionable thing I could see at a quick glance is in the `Comparator`, where `I1.s <= I2.s` maybe should be `I1.s < I2.s` instead.

Comment: @Paul R I've never used valgrind, I'll try it.

Comment: Please show us a possible input

Comment: @Jabberwocky I only have the example input provided on that link and I've added that to the question.

Comment: what if `T < 0`?

Comment: @rsp I've added the constraints too.

Comment: Why is `K` unused in your code?

Comment: @rsp because of unordered_map I didn't need it. As 1 <= p <= K, after all the input is taken, unordered_map size will be K so R.cend()-R.cbegin() will be K. K is given in case if someone made a data structure like vector<vector<Interval>> R(K), here they will have to specify K.  I thought p can take any value from 1 to 10^9 (range of K) which is why I made an unordered_map. I'll try that second method now.

Comment: Your comparator is not a strict weak ordering. This causes undefined behaviour in `std::sort`.

Comment: @molbdnilo how? I mean isn't that how you sort names by last name first then first name.

Comment: @lucieon `std::sort` requires a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). For instance, if `a` is ordered before `b`, then `b` can't also be ordered before `a` (as can be the case in your code).

Comment: @molbdnilo ok. I removed the 2nd condition which is not necessary.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. It worked! @molbdnilo but can you explain why was that giving me a Runtime error for that mistake? Shouldn't it be giving wrong answer?

Comment: @lucieon As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything, or nothing, might happen.